# visualize code indentation

Tags: indentation, code

How can I visualize code indentation? What I want is to draw a vertical line along the indentation. Since an example is easier to show then to explain you can see one in [this paper](http://ijcai.org/papers09/Papers/IJCAI09-303.pdf) (on page 2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "algorithm2e" package a short example is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\SetAlgoLined
\begin{procedure}
\Switch{the value of T}{
  \uCase{a value}{
    do this\;
    do that\;
  }
  \lCase{another value}{one line}\;
  \Case{last value}{
    do this\;
    break\;
  }
  \Other{
    for the other values\;
    do that\;
  }
}
\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Yiannis: Did you read the question? It clearly says "What I want is to draw a vertical line along the indentation."

Comment: @Hendrik I read the part ..."you can see one in this paper (on page 2)", that clearly shows code that was typeset with `alogorithm2e`. How did you understand it?

Comment: @Yiannis: On page 2, I see that there are vertical lines along the indentation. And the OP asks how to reproduce that.

Comment: @Hendrik The only thing missing from Yiannis's answer is the line `\SetAlgoVlined` (or `\SetAlgoLined` depending on the style you want.)

Comment: @Alan: Well, then that's the _essential_ thing missing. From how I read the question, this was the only thing the OP wanted to know. But: Thanks for the info; maybe you want to post a separate answer, or Yiannis edits his answer.

Comment: @Hendrik Yes, that's absolutely true :-) so your initial comment was right on target.  I guess I'd prefer to wait for Yiannis to update his answer, since identifying the `algorithm2e` package was also important.  Hopefully Mene is reading the comments.

Comment: @Alan @Hendrik Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Yiannis. One point for users with older installations: In previous versions of `algorithms2e` it was `\SetLine`, not `\SetAlgoLined`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers! I was using `lstlisting` till now. I'm not yet sure if the differences between the two options aren't too big, since I prefer the rest of `lstlisting`.